# Hashem vindicates Sarah's jealousy?

Tags: abraham, vayera, yishmael, avraham-ibn-ezra

According to the [Ibn Ezra (21,9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.21.9?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.21.9.1&lang2=bi), Sarah's demand to banish Yishmael was based purely on jealousy. Why would Hashem agree with her and instruct Avraham to send him away?

Comment: Because God understands jealousy. Part of the whole jealous God thing

Comment: Exodus 34:14 *for the Lord whose name is Jealous, is a jealous God;*

Comment: Maybe she felt that unless Avraham had actually transferred a portion of his love from Sarah to Hagar, then Hagar would not have been so emboldened.

Answer (score 1):

Ibn Ezra says that she was jealous because Yishmael was older. Presumably he means that because he was older, he would be the firstborn of Avraham, not Yitzchak. Hashem says Sarah was right to insist that Yitzchak be the main inheritor of Avraham, not Yishmael.

Comment: Thanks @N.T. for that, the Ibn Ezra leaves a lot for interpretation because he doesn't explicate much so I understand that is a possibility.

Comment: The Ibn Ezra is famous for his terseness.